# Iterate conditionally through array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I want to break an array into an array of arrays.

```
test_ary = %w(101 This is the first label 102 This is the second label 103 This is
the third label 104 This is the fourth label)

result = iterate_array(test_ary)
```

Expected output:

```
#⇒ [
#    "101 This is the first label",
#    "102 This is the second label",
#    "103 This is the third label",
#    "104 This is the fourth label" ]
```

I wrote the following method:

```
def iterate_array(ary)
  temp_ary = []
  final_ary =[]
  idx = 0
    temp_ary.push ary[idx]
    idx +=1
    done = ary.length - 1
    while idx <= done
        if ary[idx] =~ /\d/
            final_ary.push temp_ary
            temp_ary = []
            temp_ary.push ary[idx]
        else
            temp_ary.push ary[idx]
        end
        idx +=1
    end
    final_ary.push temp_ary
    returned_ary=final_ary.map {|nested_ary| nested_ary.join(" ")}
    returned_ary
end
```

I think there must be an easier and more elegant way. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi M, it would help if you would include the expected output, it would help to clean up some of your formatting errors.

Comment: Sorry folks. I'm just catching on to the formatting. Hopefully I cleaned it up (w the help of Vlad)- M

Answer (score 3):

I would use `Enumerable#slice_before`:

```
test_ary.slice_before { |w| w =~ /\d/ }.map { |ws| ws.join(" ") }
# => ["101 This is the first label", "102 This is the second label", "103 This is the third label", "104 This is the fourth label"]
```

Edit: As @mwp said, you can make this even shorter:

```
test_ary.slice_before(/\d/).map { |ws| ws.join(" ") }
# => ["101 This is the first label", "102 This is the second label", "103 This is the third label", "104 This is the fourth label"]
```

Comment: Quite nice! I like this better than slice_when. slice_before can take a pattern argument so it can be simplified a bit to `words.slice_before(/\d/)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
▶ test_ary.join(' ').split(/ (?=\d)/)
#⇒ [
#  [0] "101 This is the first label",
#  [1] "102 This is the second label",
#  [2] "103 This is the third label",
#  [3] "104 This is the fourth label"
# ]
```

Comment: Thx muda. Using regex goes a long long way

Comment: Welcome erel, I am unable to understand what you meant, though.

Answer (score 1):

This will iterate through the array two elements at a time and "break" (slice) it when the right-hand side is a number (or as it's written, when the right-hand side does not contain any non-digit characters). Hope this helps!

```
test_ary.slice_when { |_, r| r !~ /\D/ }.map { |w| w.join(' ') }
```

Comment: That's a pretty good use of a regex. But that assumes the array should always break when its numeric. Good answer nonetheless. +1

Comment: Thanks @Vlad. It makes some strong assumptions about the input, but I can only work off of whatever information is available in the original question!

Comment: Thanks mwp. I guess I'm relying too much on the basic Array class docs at ruby-doc.org.  I found info on #slice_when and #slice_between on the ruby-lang.org. But I'm confused: when I enter Array.methods, shouldn't slice_when, which Array should inherit from Enumerable, show up? It doesn't...

Comment: Try `Array.instance_methods`. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the output your function gives me, with `%w(101 This is the first label 102 This is the second label 103 This is the third label 104 This is the fourth label).each { |x| puts x }` or using `map` I get the same result. It would help if you can post your expected output.